# Is this the correct way to use the AWS global config in the JavaScript SDK?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-javascript-sdk

The way AWS gets configured strikes me as really odd. You can apparently set the config in one file, and then you don't have to `export` the configured AWS object, you can just import it straight from node modules again. I'm having a hard time understanding how/why this works:

```
// config.js
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')
AWS.config.update({ region: 'us-east-2', signatureVersion: 'v4' })
```

Then in some other file, I can just import AWS like this, and the config magically sticks with it:

```
// some other js file
const AWS = require('aws-sdk') // look, I didn't import this from config.js!
const s3 = new AWS.S3() // it knows how to use the right region & signature!
```

Why shouldn't I export the AWS that I configured and import that instead? How is the configuration copied over even when I'm not importing it from my config file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at the [source code](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/blob/c578c8346494654914efb335779ca2620c3e6b36/lib/config.js) you can see that the `AWS` object has `config` a property which is initialized.

This is essentially [singleton object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern), it relies on [module caching](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_caching) in Node.js.

From the NodeJS docs:

> **Caching**
>
> Modules are cached after the first time they are loaded. This means
> (among other things) that every call to require('foo') will get
> exactly the same object returned, if it would resolve to the same
> file.
>
> Provided require.cache is not modified, multiple calls to
> require('foo') will not cause the module code to be executed multiple
> times. This is an important feature. With it, "partially done" objects
> can be returned, thus allowing transitive dependencies to be loaded
> even when they would cause cycles.
>
> To have a module execute code multiple times, export a function, and
> call that function.

Comment: Great explanation. It is a little unsettling because I am so used to the pattern others use which is import > config > export then you use the exported object throughout the rest of your project. It feels wrong to just do the config and not export it. How does this not create a race condition? I guess as long as the config happens at run time it won't?